# How to update an svg path with d3.js

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I'd like to apply the ["general update pattern"](https://gist.github.com/mbostock/3808218) from official documentation to update an svg path on the mouse event (but could be a button or whatever).

But the the path is only added and not updated. I think it's why I'm not properly using the `enter` and `exit` property but after some various trial, I cannot manage to let it work.

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AKrda/).

My js code is here:

```
var shapeCoords = [
                  [10, 10], [100, 10], [100, 100], [10, 100]                  
                  ];

$(function() {
    var container = $('#container');

    // D3
    console.log("D3: ", d3);

    var svg = d3.select('#container')
                .append('svg:svg')
                .attr('height', 600)
                .attr('width', 800);

    var line = d3.svg.line()
                    .x(function(d) { return d[0]; })
                    .y(function(d) { return d[1]; })
                    .interpolate('linear');

    function render() {

            svg.data(shapeCoords)
                .append('svg:path')
                .attr('d', line(shapeCoords) + 'Z')
                .style('stroke-width', 1)
                .style('stroke', 'steelblue');
    }
    render();

    var mouseIsDown = false;  
    container.on('mousedown mouseup mousemove', function(e) {
        if (e.type == 'mousedown') {
            mouseIsDown = true; 
            shapeCoords[3] = [e.offsetX, e.offsetY];
        } else if (e.type == 'mouseup' ){
            mouseIsDown = false;
            shapeCoords[3] = [e.offsetX, e.offsetY];
        } else if (e.type == 'mousemove') {
            if (mouseIsDown) {
                shapeCoords[3] = [e.offsetX, e.offsetY];
                render();
            }
        }
    });


});
```

And the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>D3 mousemove</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" 
            src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" 
            src="http://mbostock.github.com/d3/d3.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    <style>
        #container { 
            width: 800px; 
            height: 600px; 
            border: 1px solid silver; }
        path, line {
            stroke: steelblue;
            stroke-width: 1;
            fill: none;
        }
    </style>
</head> 
<body>   
    <div id="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your code isn't selecting an existing element, so instead of updating the "d" attribute of an existing path via the `update` selection, it's appending a new path each time. This version of `render()` produced the expected behavior. More on selections [here](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#d3_select).

```
function render() {
    path = svg.selectAll('path').data([shapeCoords])
    path.attr('d', function(d){return line(d) + 'Z'})
        .style('stroke-width', 1)
        .style('stroke', 'steelblue');
    path.enter().append('svg:path').attr('d', function(d){return line(d) + 'Z'})
        .style('stroke-width', 1)
        .style('stroke', 'steelblue');
    path.exit().remove()
```

Once you run the data join on `path` via `.data()`, operations performed on `path` will only apply to the update selection. Meaning, only those existing elements that still have corresponding data elements under the new join. When you call `enter().append()` it will append a new element for every data element without a pre-existing element, and then apply the following operations only to those elements.

In the above, the first `path.attr()` above operates only on existing elements; those applied after `path.enter()` apply only to new elements. It's not featured in the snippet above, but `enter()` adds the enter selection to the update selection: any operations on `path` after calling `enter()` would apply to both existing and new elements.

Comment: why do you repeat the `attr('d')` ?

Comment: I mean, why do you change first the `attr` of a "d" on the path and then you add more "d" via `enter().append()` ?

Comment: The first `attr("d")` only works on the existing elements, and the subsequent `attr("d")` adds a `d` attribute to the new elements. (Full explanation added above.) Cheers!

Answer (score 5):

Please try the following code, I think it's what you want. The problem is caused because you should distinguish enter, update and exit when you want to update elements, otherwise it will add data again and again.

```
$(function() {
var container = $('#container');

// D3
console.log("D3: ", d3);

var svg = d3.select('#container')
            .append('svg:svg')
            .attr('height', 600)
            .attr('width', 800);

var line = d3.svg.line()
                .x(function(d) { return d[0]; })
                .y(function(d) { return d[1]; })
                .interpolate('linear');

svg.data(shapeCoords)
    .append('svg:path')
    .attr('d', line(shapeCoords) + 'Z')
    .style('stroke-width', 1)
    .style('stroke', 'steelblue');

function render() {

    var svg = d3.select('#container').select("svg").selectAll('path').data(shapeCoords);
    svg.enter().append('svg:path')
            .attr('d', line(shapeCoords) + 'Z')
            .style('stroke-width', 1)
            .style('stroke', 'steelblue');
    svg.attr('d', line(shapeCoords) + 'Z')
            .style('stroke-width', 1)
            .style('stroke', 'steelblue');    
    svg.exit().remove();    

}
render();
```

Comment: sorry but why do you bind the data 3 times??

Comment: @nkint I just wanted to show the result and didn't care about that. Sure no need to do that 3 times, I reedit it, thanks.