# Manipulate elements in SVG file (object) by JavaScript or JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg

I have a challenge of manipulating SVG file (object) in html code. There are solutions in Snap, Raphael but I need to do it directly by either JavaScript or JQuery. That's what I have so far:

JS:

```
<object id="testSVG" data="image_library/grandstaff_drawing_only.svg"       
type="image/svg+xml" height=100% width=100%">
<img src="image_library/alto-clef.png" />
</object>

 <script>

window.onload=function() {
// Get the Object by ID
var a = document.getElementById("testSVG");
// Get the SVG document inside the Object tag
var svgDoc = a.contentDocument;
// Get one of the SVG items by ID;
var svgItem = svgDoc.getElementById("path3380");
// Set the colour to something else
//svgItem.setAttribute("stroke", "red");
svgItem.style.stroke = "#ff0000";
};

</script>
```

JQuery:

```
<object id="testSVG" data="image_library/grandstaff_drawing_only.svg"    
type="image/svg+xml" height=100% width=100%">
<img src="image_library/alto-clef.png" />
</object>


<script>

window.onload=function() {
var svgDoc = $(“#testSVG”)[0].contentDocument; 
$(“#path3380”, svgDoc).css(“stroke”, “red”); 

};

</script>
```

Thank you!!!

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normally I use D3.js library when I want to create or manipulate SVG graphics by javascript alone. http://d3js.org/

Unlike libs like Raphaeljs, which polyfills, D3 provides a javascript API for direct manipulation of SVG elements within the browser in real time.

> **D3 is Not a SVG Polyfill:** 
>   Unlike Raphaël, which provides polyfill for SVG on browsers that do not support SVG. D3 manipulates SVG directly, without any abstraction layer. Your browser needs to support SVG for D3 to work properly.
>   ([source](http://ruoyusun.com/2014/05/26/what-d3js-is-not.html))

For example, here's a demo I made from a D3 tutorial that constructs and manipulates SVG elements to create a live javascript / svg driven clock using the Javascript native `new Date()` function: http://jsfiddle.net/2jogwx6x/1/

The D3.js strategy will likely work for your purposes and the elem selection method is similar to jQuery's CSS selection method but working directly with dom nodes, but for it to work you would need to directly embed your SVG data into the DOM like:

```
<!-- simple rectangle - replace this with your real svg data -->
<svg width="400" height="110">
    <rect width="300" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);stroke-width:3;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)">
</svg>
```

Instead of using `<object id="testSVG" data="image_library/grandstaff_drawing_only.svg" type="image/svg+xml" height=100% width=100%">`

To manipulate SVG data in the DOM on the fly it has to be a part of the DOM and not opening / writing to / closing an external file.

Comment: See this SO thread if you want more specific detail on changing svg path and stroke colour of an SVG img using D3: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22621865/how-to-update-an-svg-path-with-d3-js

Comment: Hi all. Thank you, DrewT, for your comments. Paul LeBeau, I try to manipulate an EXTERNAL SVG file by either JavaScript or JQuery without using Raphael , Snap etc. There could be more over 10 SVG files and each one could be quite lengthy, so I try to avoid Inline SVG XML Embedded Into HTML Page. What is wrong with the code I posted (either JS or JQuery)? It loads the object "testSVG" but I can not manipulate a separate element (e.g. "path3380") to change color of stroke. How can I do it? Thank you.

Comment: @LearnForever You ignored the part of my post that explains that particular problem: **"To manipulate SVG data in the DOM on the fly it has to be a part of the DOM and not opening / writing to / closing an external file."** If you need to do it for many SVG files, load them inline dynamically. If you were using `php` you could use `file_get_contents()` but you need them inside the DOM or else you can't manipulate properties without writing data inside the file itself which would 1) CHANGE the files real internal contents 2) Pose server problems for simultaneous users accessing the same image

Comment: I see now. Thank you for follow-up, DrewT. I really appreciate it.