# Draw SVG path on top of tree. Cannot update path

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I am drwaing D3 collapsive tree as [here](http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/8375092)
and want to draw some path between nodes. The problem is that when the tree branch is collapsed, old path is not removed. Similar solution is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22621865/how-to-update-an-svg-path-with-d3-js#) but I do something wrong. Could you please advise how I should update SVG path?

Code for init, update path:

```
 var path = svg.selectAll('path.sce').data(nodes);
  path.attr('d', lineFunction(nodes))
      .style('stroke-width', 2)
      .style('stroke', 'black')
      .attr('class', 'arrow')
      .attr('fill', 'none')
      .attr('marker-end', 'url(#arrow)');

  path.enter().append('svg:path').attr('d', lineFunction(nodes))
      .style('stroke-width', 2)
      .style('stroke', 'black')
      .attr('class', 'arrow')
      .attr('fill', 'none')
      .attr('marker-end', 'url(#arrow)');

  path.exit().remove();
```

Full code - [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hhaqvwtq/2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is very simple: for your update and exit selections to work, you have to select the same class that you set in your enter selection:

```
var path = svg.selectAll('.arrow');
```

Here is your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/odf3q84L/