# D3 linkHorizontal() update on mouse position

Tags: vue.js, d3.js

I’m trying to implement a drag and drop functionality with a connection line. The connection line has a starting point ([x, y]), which is gathered when the mouse is clicked and a target point ([x, y]) which follows the mouse position and is continuously updated while dragging the element.
The project uses Vue.JS with VUEX store and for the connection line D3.js (linkHorizontal method https://bl.ocks.org/shivasj/b3fb218a556bc15e36ae3152d1c7ec25).

In the main component I have a div where the SVG is inserted:

```
<div id="svg_lines"></div>
```

In the main.js File I watch the current mouse position (targetPos), get the start position from the VUEX store (sourcePos) and pass it on to connectTheDots(sourcePos, targetPos).

```
new Vue({
router,
store,
render: (h) => h(App),
async created() {
    window.document.addEventListener('dragover', (e) => {
        e = e || window.event;
        var dragX = e.pageX, dragY = e.pageY;
        store.commit('setConnMousePos', {"x": dragX, "y": dragY});
        
        let sourcePos = this.$store.getters.getConnStartPos;
        let targetPos = this.$store.getters.getConnMousePos;

        // draw the SVG line
        connectTheDots(sourcePos, targetPos);

    }, false)
  },
 }).$mount('#app');
```

The connectTheDots() function receives sourcePos and targetPos as arguments and should update the target position of D3 linkHorizontal. Here is what I have:

```
function connectTheDots(sourcePos, targetPos) {
const offset = 2;
const shapeCoords = [{
    source: [sourcePos.y + offset, sourcePos.x + offset],
    target: [targetPos.y + offset, targetPos.x + offset],
}];

let svg = d3.select('#svg_lines')
    .append('svg')
    .attr('class', 'test_svgs');

let link = d3.linkHorizontal()
    .source((d) => [d.source[1], d.source[0]])
    .target((d) => [d.target[1], d.target[0]]);

function render() {
    let path = svg.selectAll('path').data(shapeCoords)
    path.attr('d', function (d) {
        return link(d) + 'Z'
    })
    path.enter().append('svg:path').attr('d', function (d) {
        return link(d) + 'Z'
    })
    path.exit().remove()
}

render();
}
```

I stole/modified the code from this post [How to update an svg path with d3.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22621865/how-to-update-an-svg-path-with-d3-js), but can’t get it to work properly.
Instead of updating the path, the function just keeps adding SVGs. See attached images:

[Web app: Multiple SVGs are drawn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/00ucB.png)

[Console: Multiple SVGs are added to element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ge442.png)

What am I missing here?

Comment: let svg = d3.select('#svg_lines')
    .append('svg')
    .attr('class', 'test_svgs'); Why are you appending svg everytime connectthedots is called. it should be appended outside the function and should be used in function only to update

Comment: Right, that's of course why it's keeps adding connections! Thanks @BKalra. I will add my solution as an answer to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@BKalra helped me solve this.

This line keeps appending new SVGs:

```
let svg = d3.select('#svg_lines') .append('svg') .attr('class', 'test_svgs');
```

So I removed it from the connectTheDots() function.

Here is my solution:

In the main component I added an SVG with a path:

```
<div id="svg_line_wrapper">
  <svg class="svg_line_style">
    <path
        d="M574,520C574,520,574,520,574,520Z"
    ></path>
  </svg>
</div>
```

In the connectTheDots() function I don't need to append anymore, I just grap the SVG and update its path:

```
function connectTheDots(sourcePos, targetPos) {
  const offset = 2;
  const data = [{
    source: [sourcePos.y + offset, sourcePos.x + offset],
    target: [targetPos.y + offset, targetPos.x + offset],
  }];
  let link = d3.linkHorizontal()
    .source((d) => [d.source[1], d.source[0]])
    .target((d) => [d.target[1], d.target[0]]);

  d3.select('#svg_line_wrapper')
    .selectAll('path')
    .data(data)
    .join('path')
    .attr('d', link)
    .classed('link', true)
}
```